# Pass data frame as argument, and return vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, return

Hi all thank you for your answers. I have found the problem to be the step `impVolCall[i] <- sig` 
cannot work, since somehow impVolCall is of class integer and sig cannot be written into.
Adding as.numeric(impVolCall) in and out the function would resolve the problem.

Thanks! :)

I'm quite new in R so not sure if this question may appear too silly for you..

I created a function to calculate implied volatility using bisection method and bs76 formula. It worked fun when the function takes in arguments in the format of

```
implied.vol <-  function(S, K, T, market, type = "call", r = 0.02)
```

I want to make this function such that it takes only one data frame, and each row of the data frame represents an option. The function will return all implied volatility in one single vector, then my complete code looks like below.

The result is always 
    `> resCall`
   `[1] 1 2 3` 
Which is the number of rows with "c"

Could any 1 enlighten if my way of passing data frame is wrong?
Thanks.

```
myOptData <- read.csv(file="optionData.csv", header=TRUE)

 df <-
  data.frame(myOptData$strike, myOptData$type, myOptData$optionPrice, 
         myOptData$futurePrice, myOptData$time_to_maturity)




bs <- function (type = "call", spot, strike, maturity, sigma, drift = 0.02)  
{

  d1 <- 1/sigma/sqrt(maturity)*(log(spot/strike)+(sigma^2/2)*maturity)
  d2 <- d1 - sigma*sqrt(maturity)

  call <- (pnorm(d1)*spot - pnorm(d2)*strike)*exp(-drift*maturity)
  put  <- (pnorm(-d2)*strike - pnorm(-d1)*spot)*exp(-drift*maturity)


  result <- c(call, put)
  names(result) <- c("call", "put")
  result[type]
}

## Function to find BS Implied Vol using Bisection Method



implied.vol <-
  function(df) 
  {
    sig <- 0.25
    sig.up <- 1
    sig.down <- 0.001
    count <- 0`

    numOfCall <- nrow(df[df$type == "c",])
    numOfPut <- nrow(df[df$type == "p",])

    impVOlCall <- 1:numOfCall
    impVolPut <- 1:numOfPut

    dfSorted <- df[order(df$type),]

    for (i in seq(impVolCall)) 
    {

    err <- 
        bs(dfSorted[i,2], dfSorted[i,4], dfSorted[i,1], dfSorted[i,5], sig,    0.02) - dfSorted[i,3]

    ## repeat until error is sufficiently small or counter hits 1000

    while(abs(err) > 0.00001 && count<1000)
    {
      if(err < 0)
      {
        sig.down <- sig
        sig <- (sig.up + sig)/2
      }
      else
      {
        sig.up <- sig
        sig <- (sig.down + sig)/2
      }
      err <- bs(dfSorted[i,2], dfSorted[i,4], dfSorted[i,1], dfSorted[i,5], sig, 0.02 ) - dfSorted[i,3]
      count <- count + 1
    }

    ## return NA if counter hit 1000

    if(count==1000)
    {
      impVolCall[i] <- NA
    }

    else
    {
     # plot(K, sig, main = type, xlab = "Strike", ylab="Option Price")
      impVolCall[i] <- sig
    }

    }

    return (impVOlCall)
  }



resCall <- 1:nrow(myOptData[myOptData$type == "c",])

resCall <- implied.vol(myOptData)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: We don't know what your data looks like, so we can't work out what's wrong. Could you simplify the function to the smallest thing that reproduces the problem and add a five-row dummy data set?

Comment: You some errors in your code. In line 10 of the `implied.vol` function code, you assign number of rows to `impVOlCall`. Then you call it up again as `impVolCall`. Your `return` call once again uses `impVOlCall`, which is just the index of row names. Refer to the object consistently throughout the function.

Comment: I found the problem already and added in the question body. Thank you guys :)